# How to store a 2 by 2 frd model into a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to store frd variables which contains 3000 frequency points with one input and one output (2 by 2 matrix) into a matrix. How can I do?

I am trying to store it in matrix but getting error as 'Unable to perform assignment because value of type 'frd' is not convertible to double'

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding tags to your question which aren't relevant. Please also [edit] your question to show a [mcve] so we might be able to help debug

Comment: try with a 2x2 cell array instead. If you could expand more about the data you are using we may be able to give you a more specific solution

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you probably need a cell array, or rather a combination of cell + double array. For example:

```
inputOutput1 = [1,2]; % using a normal matrix
inputOutput2 = [3,4]; 
inputOutputMatrix = {inputOutput1, inputOutput2} % using a cell matrix
```

This is probably the most straightforward solution for your data, and should still perform fine with 3000 entries. See also the documentation on cell arrays for further info:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html

Edit in response to beaker, who was right in noticing that you can also use a multidimensional array. To add to the last example:

```
inputOutput1 = [1,2];
inputOutput2 = [3,4]; 
inputOutputMatrix(:,:,1) = inputOutput1;
inputOutputMatrix(:,:,2) = inputOutput2;
```

In this case, this is better assuming you always have only one input and one output.

Comment: Why a cell array? The variables being stored are a uniform size, so a multidimensional array will store the data more efficiently and have faster access.